# How to activate Python env in the local directory and run pdoc with pre-commit?

Tags: python, github-actions, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, pdoc

I have recently created a GitHub Actions workflow to lint/reformat the code of my repo and create documentation HTML pages using [pdoc](https://pdoc.dev/). The last step is problematic, because pdoc runs the .py files to create the documentation. For one of the files (file.py) the ServiceNow ODBC driver needs to be set up and it's unfeasible to do on every workflow. That is why I decided to try using pdoc with pre-commit. Locally the pdoc command only works if pdoc is in the same directory as file.py, that is why a virtual env has to be activated before running the command

My configuration is Windows 10 and Python 3.9. These are the commands:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
pdoc ./file.py -o ./docs
```

This is the .pre-commit-config.yaml I tried:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml

-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: env
      name: Activate env
      language: system
      entry: .\env\Scripts\activate

-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: pdoc
      name: Run pdoc
      language: system
      entry: pdoc ./file.py -o ./docs


# Output:

check yaml...............................................................Passed
Activate env.............................................................Failed
- hook id: env
- exit code: 1
Executable `.envScriptsactivate` not found
Run pdoc.................................................................Failed
- hook id: pdoc
- exit code: 1
Executable `pdoc` not found
```

This may not be intuitive use of pre-commit, but I need a way to run the pdoc commands before every commit. This is intended for use inside the same organization, so the set up will be the same on every device.

**Edit 1:**
I tried one of the suggestions from [anthony sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile), but there are still some errors because of unexpected arguments.

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml

-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: env
      name: Activate env
      language: system
      entry: ./env/Scripts/pdoc.exe file.py -o ./packages

# Output:

check yaml...............................................................Passed
Activate env.............................................................Failed
- hook id: env
- exit code: 2
usage: pdoc.exe [-o DIR] [-d {markdown,google,numpy,restructuredtext}]
                [-e module=url] [--favicon URL] [--footer-text TEXT]
                [--logo URL] [--logo-link URL] [--math | --no-math]
                [--search | --no-search] [--show-source | --no-show-source]
                [-t DIR] [-h HOST] [-p PORT] [-n] [--help] [--version]
                [module ...]
pdoc.exe: error: unrecognized arguments: .idea/misc.xml .idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml .pre-commit-config.yaml file.py
```

Comment: Since you tagged this with `github-actions`, it's also worth pointing out that pdoc has a tutorial for building docs as part of CI and pushing them to GitHub Pages: https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#deploying-to-github-pages

Comment: @MaximilianHils I already tried running it like in the example in the pdoc documentation and it worked for most of my Python files. Some files need to use the ServiceNow ODBC driver, which I can't setup in github actions and only runs locally. That means those files would be left out of the automatic documentation. Since you're involved with making pdoc, do you think it would be possible to add an option to create documentation even if there are errors running the code? Or maybe to create a pre-commit hook for pdoc?

Comment: pdoc has a strong focus on simplicity, so it's unlikely that I will add an additional option for this. The best (dare I say correct) approach here is to install dependencies in CI. If that's really not possible you could write a small Python script that mocks them and then uses pdoc as a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestions of [anthony sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile) the following changes to the .pre-commit-config.yaml worked for me:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml

-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: env
      name: Activate env
      language: system
      pass_filenames: false
      entry: ./env/Scripts/pdoc.exe ./file.py -o ./packages
```

Answer (score 0):

"activating" a virtualenv is simply prepending `PATH` (and `VIRTUAL_ENV`, though this usually doesn't do anything)

the `activate` script isn't something you execute, it's something you *source* as it has to modify the shell environment

fortunately, you don't *need* to actually source it -- you can just run the executable as normal

you've got a couple options -- the first is to access the executable directly:

```yaml
        entry: venv\Scripts\pdoc -o docs
```

this is kind of a bad idea though as it's non-portable -- `Scripts` is only a thing on windows

a better option would be to assume it's already on the `PATH` and put nothing in your `pre-commit` configuration:

```yaml
        entry: pdoc -o docs
```

and then add to the `PATH` in your github actions steps:

```yaml
    - run: echo "$PWD/venv/Scripts" >> "$GITHUB_PATH"
      shell: bash
```

even this isn't great because it means you always need to have `pdoc` on the `PATH` when working locally (meaning you can't commit without your virtualenv activated).  this kind of goes against the design of `pre-commit` where *it manages your tools* so you don't have to.  you may be able to use `additional_dependencies` to install `pdoc` such that you don't need to depend on the state of things that are installed -- but I suspect `pdoc` needs the rest of your dependencies to properly generate its output -- **this usually is an indicator that what you're trying to do isn't a good fit for `pre-commit` in the first place**

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed answer! I tried one of your suggestions as you can see in the edit. But in general I agree that it might not be a good fit for pre-commit. Do you know a more appropriate method to achieve my goal of running pdoc locally with every commit?

Comment: well your next step would be to read the documentation about _why_ you're getting extra files and [how to control that behaviour](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-pass_filenames)

Comment: I changed pass_filenames to false and it worked, thank you!